# parallel processing - nearest neighbour search using pysal python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pysal

I have this data frame df1,

```
          id      lat_long
400743  2504043 (175.0976323, -41.1141412)
43203   1533418 (173.976683, -35.2235338)
463952  3805508 (174.6947496, -36.7437555)
1054906 3144009 (168.0105269, -46.36193)
214474  3030933 (174.6311167, -36.867717)
1008802 2814248 (169.3183615, -45.1859095)
988706  3245376 (171.2338968, -44.3884099)
492345  3085310 (174.740957, -36.8893026)
416106  3794301 (174.0106383, -35.3876921)
937313  3114127 (174.8436185, -37.80499)
```

I have constructed the tree for search here,

```
def construct_geopoints(s):
    data_geopoints = [tuple(x) for x in s[['longitude','latitude']].to_records(index=False)]
    tree = KDTree(data_geopoints, distance_metric='Arc', radius=pysal.cg.RADIUS_EARTH_KM)
    return tree

tree = construct_geopoints(actualdata)
```

Now, I am trying to search all the geopoints which are within 1KM of every geopoint in my data frame df1. Here is how I am doing,

```
dfs = []
for name,group in df1.groupby(np.arange(len(df1))//10000):
    s = group.reset_index(drop=True).copy()
    pts = list(s['lat_long'])
    neighbours = tree.query_ball_point(pts, 1)
    s['neighbours'] = pd.Series(neighbours)
    dfs.append(s)

output = pd.concat(dfs,axis = 0)
```

Everything here works fine, however I am trying to parallelise this task, since my df1 size is 2M records, this process is running for more than 8 hours. Can anyone help me on this? And another thing is, the result returned by query_ball_point is a list and so its throwing memory error when I am processing it for the huge amount of records. Any way to handle this.

EDIT :- Memory issue, look at the VIRT size.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to parallelize your last segment of code with something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
...

def process_group(group):
    s = group[1].reset_index(drop=True)  # .copy() is implicit
    pts = list(s['lat_long'])
    neighbours = tree.query_ball_point(pts, 1)
    s['neighbours'] = pd.Series(neighbours)
    return s

groups = df1.groupby(np.arange(len(df1))//10000)

p = Pool(5)
dfs = p.map(process_group, groups)

output = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
```

But watch out, because the `multiprocessing` library `pickles` all the data on its way to and from the workers, and that can add a lot of overhead for data-intensive tasks, possibly cancelling the savings due to parallel processing.

I can't see where you'd be getting out-of-memory errors from. 8 million records is not that much for pandas. Maybe if your searches are producing hundreds of matches per row that could be a problem. If you say more about that I might be able to give some more advice.

It also sounds like pysal may be taking longer than necessary to do this. You might be able to get better performance by using [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org) or "rolling your own" solution like this:

1. assign each point to a surrounding 1-km grid cell (e.g., calculate UTM coordinates `x` and `y`, then  create columns `cx=x//1000` and `cy=y//1000`);
2. create an index on the grid cell coordinates `cx` and `cy` (e.g., `df=df.set_index(['cx', 'cy'])`);
3. for each point, find the points in the 9 surrounding cells; you can select these directly from the index via `df.loc[[(cx-1,cy-1),(cx-1,cy),(cx-1,cy+1),(cx,cy-1),...(cx+1,cy+1)], :]`;
4. filter the points you just selected to find the ones within 1 km.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, let me read through this now, just to answer your memory related question, yes, each search result will give more than 1000 elements in a list.

Comment: May be is it possible to convert that as a tuple?

Comment: So you will be getting something like 8 billion elements to process (1000 matches for each of 8 million points)? That will cause memory problems. Depending on your workflow, you could either store each batch to disk for later processing, or you could process the list further within the same worker, to get it down to a manageable size before returning it, or some combination of the two.

Comment: It is not 8 Million records, its 2 Million records though. Let me update the screenshot with question. You can see how memory is building up, may be I will try to use imap instead of map to see how that utilise the memory.

Comment: Yeah, then I have to try as you suggested, I will process the list further within the same worker to get it down to manageable size before returning it.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you will need to design your solution around the memory issues. If you can't fit all the intermediate results into memory at the same time, then it makes sense to work through to the end batch-by-batch, and then save final results.